# Names of the files using subfiles package

Tags: subfiles, naming

I was wondering if there is a way to include with the subfiles package, files (in a main tex file) that don't have english names, especially in my case greek, but generally in other languages? I have tried some things, but it doen't give an output. It only outputs `όνομα_αρχείου.τεξ.τεξ` which is the file's name in greek characters. The file itself is ok, I tested it with the desired preamble to make sure it works.
[image]
**EDIT** Firstly I am using TexLive2017 (TL2017) in ubuntu 2018, texstudio. So maybe that's the problem. I am posting below a MWE.

The Θέματα.tex file (the main file)

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parcolumns,paracol,rotating,mdframed}
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    \subfile{Ε9α.tex}
\end{document}
```

The Ε9α.tex file which I use above

```
\documentclass[Θέματα.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Πρωτοχρονιά}
    
Αρχιμηνιά και αρχιχρονιά

ψηλή μου δεντρολιβανιά

\end{document}
```

I will update my TL distribution and comment if the problem is fixed.

Comment: can you provide a small test file pair that shows the problem. Also are you using pdftex or a unicode tex such as luatex or xetex?

Comment: Update your TeX distribution, LaTeX as well as the packages you use, and check  whether the problem persists. I have seen such an effect before, and it was an interference of the `import` package with `filehooks`. `import` is loaded by `subfiles`, and `filehooks` is used by various packages. I think the interference was resolved in recent versions. Otherwise, please do as David suggested: Provide a complete small sample document (with sub-files) that illustrates the problem, such that we can test and experiment with the code.

Comment: I updated my answer with extra details! The good news (as I understand from the comments) is that it is fixable. :-)

Comment: @ΝικολέταΣεβαστού I've checked your file with a recent distribution, and greek filenames work with the `subfiles` package if you use a TeX engine fit for Unicode, i.e., `xelatex` or `lualatex`. `pdflatex` will not work. If you use `xelatex` or `lualatex`, you have to set up a proper Greek font, which you are probably familiar with anyway.

Comment: Thanks for checking it. I am still trying to properly install TL 2021. I am having problems with the path, manpath and infopath. I am a little bit disappointed that it doesn't work in pdflatex because I don't use xelatex or luatex. Can I do anything else to solve the problem?

Comment: @ΝικολέταΣεβαστού How is it going? [I'm working on the issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630488/unicode-compatible-version-of-filenameparse), which is trickier than I thought, so it will take a bit until I can release a tested update of the package

Comment: @gernot Thanks a lot! I am glad that it is going to be corrected. Well I deleted TL2017, but I couldn't properly install from source TL2021. Now I must reinstall TL2017. If somebody answers my question[https://askubuntu.com/q/1387935/1444006] in askubuntu (I asked what should I do with PATH, MANPATH and INFOPATH because I had problems) I may move forward. At the moment I am waiting. Thanks for asking!